# How add dynamic user attribute value in keycloak with saml

Tags: saml-2.0, keycloak

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Keycloack 3.2
Saml2.0

**SITUATION:**
I need to add user attributes value dynamically.

**TASK:**
I need **name** attribute for my user, which can fill dynamically from First Name and Last Name fields, which as I found in keycloack can be **fullName** property.

> **NOTE:** Instead of **fullName** it can be **firstName + lastName** field in my case as well.

**ACTION:**
I added user property with name fullName under my **Clients -> myCLient -> Mappers**, [image: My Client Mappings]

then added under my user **Users -> myUser -> Attributes**, attribute key **name** and attribute value **${fullName}**.
[image: My User Details]
[image: My User Attributes]

**RESULT:**
As a result I got ${fullName} as a value instead of dynamic value from my predefined user property.

**QUESTIONS:**

> 1. Is it possible to do this kind of things what I need ?
> 2. If it's possible then, what are wrong in my steps here?

Answer (score 1):

For users like me who looking for a solution of this problem with newest version of Keycloak, in keycloak 18.0 you can create a Mapper with the type **Javascript Mapper** with this code: `user.getFirstName() + ' ' + user.getLastName()`.

Comment: Interesting! I'm running RH-SSO 7.6.1 which is based on Keycloak 18.x but can't find a mapper of type **Javascript Mapper**. Is there a specific feature to enable at startup to make it available?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I found that under client in keylock we have builtin user properties.
Example X500 givenName, X500 surname can be added and can get in BE side as a part of SAML assertion attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution if the user federation are LDAP or Active Directory

On the user federation you can use the full-name-ldap-mapper.
[image]

By default it uses cn, but you can change that.
[image]

Next in your client you would add a saml mapper.

```json
{
    "name": "fullName",
    "protocol": "saml",
    "protocolMapper": "saml-user-attribute-mapper",
    "consentRequired": false,
    "config": {
        "attribute.nameformat": "Unspecified",
        "user.attribute": "full name",
        "friendly.name": "Full name",
        "attribute.name": "displayName"
    }
}
```

Remember the attribute.name is the property that the SP would use.
Also the nameformat has to be discussed with the SP.